# Image of morphism of locally of finite type has a closed point?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be finite dimensional locally Noetherian regular scheme. Let $f \colon X \rightarrow S$ be  locally of finite type.
Then $f(X) \subset S $ contains a closed point of $S$?
If it does, I'd like to know the proof.

Comment: Consider the case that $S$ is the spectrum of a DVR, and $X$ the spectrum of its field of fractions.